# Access localhost, Mac Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm running a local http server on port 3000 and i'd like to access that server using an Android emulator. I've tried the following in the browser:

- localhost:3000 //
- 127.0.0.1:3000 // of course I gave my local ip a try
- 10.0.3.2:3000  // I think this is a genymotion ip?
- 10.0.2.2:3000  // The most prevailing suggestion was to use this ip

With each of these i'm given this error:
[image]

Interestingly when accessing the same in chrome on my desktop:

```
localhost:3000 // works
127.0.0.1:3000 // doesn't work
```

Perhaps this is connected? I'm not sure why `127.0.0.1:3000` doesn't work, but that might be a different hurdle altogether.

My `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I've already tried reloading (& disabling) my firewall and proxies.

The emulator i'm using is:

```
Mac, Android Studio 1.5.1
Emulator : Nexus 5 - API 21, Android 5.0 x86
```

Comment: `10.0.3.2` It should work

Comment: trun off the firewall.

Comment: i've tried 10.0.3.2 @waki, it's not working

Comment: I've tried turning off the firewarll @SohailZahid, it's not working

Comment: have you try without port number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following Service

https://ngrok.com/

It will give you a tunnel to localhost and give you a URL which you can use from anywhere in the world ;)